# KO: looking up ID in VM array to populate span & choose select option

Tags: knockout.js

I'm having some difficulty figuring out what is wrong with the following KO setup.
http://jsfiddle.net/edsinek/m4rUz/

I'm simulating the data I'll be getting from the server (via a hard coded data struct), hence the use of IDs throughout.  I'm trying to populate the text of a span and what I've got is an ID that I want to use to lookup the name in the array in the VM.

The same goes for the select - I want the value to be preselected based on the ID.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some places you're missing a `()` when accessing observables, and in your binding strings you were missing `$root.` prefix for the functions.

Also, the return value from inside a `$.each` callback only serves to signal the $.each loop to stop (if you return false). You can't return a value from inside the $.each callback and expect it to return a value from the outer function. So I changed your `materialById` function  to the commented version (but added the `()` for the observableArray).

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/m4rUz/2/